# jQuery Validate method not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I'm trying to use jquery javascript validator and i cannot get this to fire at all. Can someone look over this is look for an issue

```
  $('#BtnAdd').click(function( event ) {
        $('#WorkOrderFrm').validate({
            rules: {
                Project_ID: {
                        required: true,
                    }
            },
            messages: {
                Project_ID: {
                        required: "Please enter first",
                    }
            },
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: form.action,
                    type: form.method,
                    data: $(form).serialize(),
                    success: function(response) {
                        //$('#answers').html(response);
                        alert(response);
                    }            
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call `$('#WorkOrderFrm').validate()` in your `$(document).ready()` function, not in the `click` handler.

Comment: How do i start the validation when a user clicks the #BtnAdd button?

Comment: It's done automatically when you click a submit button.

Comment: @LukeSmith, all of this is in the official documentation, the SO page wiki, and the [thousands of code examples tagged with jQuery Validate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-validate).

Comment: @Barmar im trying to use a bootstrap "button" that isnt a submit button how i do i use that and not a submit button

Comment: @LukeSmith, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11068130/594235)

Comment: @LukeSmith, to use other elements in place of proper submit buttons, you would simply call the `.submit()` event from within a `.click()` handler.  See:  https://jsfiddle.net/qj7cnxvh/

Comment: @sparky this fires the form and ignore the submit handler, im trying to submit with ajax

is there any workaround?

Comment: @LukeSmith, it absolutely does not "ignore" the `submitHandler`.  The `submitHandler` WILL fire if/when the form is valid.  See:  https://jsfiddle.net/1g5mkr7L/